# First present view controller and then push child view controllers

Tags: swift, push, viewcontroller

Is there a trick to push to child view controllers from a parent vc that previously has been presented modally?

Method to present parent that I'm using:

```
    let parentVC = ParentController()
    self.present(parentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Method to then push to child controllers which doesn't work:

```
    let childVC = childController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(childVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, But try `parentVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(childVC, animated: true)`

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a self.navigationController?.pushViewcontroller(childVC, animated: true)? I've tried that, but no luck.

Comment: @moopoints I think this is not embedded in to the `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a trick to push to child view controllers from a parent vc
>   that previously has been presented modally?

If you present a `vc` modally and you want this `vc` to push a `child vc`, you have to present the `vc` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

```
    let parentVC = ParentController()
    self.present(parentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to become

```
    let parentVC = ParentController()
    let parentNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: parentVC)
    self.present(parentNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then you can do, in `parentVC`:

```
    let childVC = childController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(childVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Following up on this - I noticed that the animation when pushing from the modal view is different than from push to push. It appears to be sliding in from the top right corner (instead of the entire view sliding in horizontally). Is there a way to turn that off / switch to the default horizontal slide? Note here, I have the navigation bar set to hidden and am using a custom nav bar in case that is important for this.

Comment: I am not sure if I can visualize your problem right here because the `pushViewController` is default horizontally sliding. You may open a new question to provide more details of your code.